# Where did Taylor Mason find their new partner?

Tags: plot-explanation, billions

In the 4th season of *Billions*, after founding Mason Capital we see Taylor's new COO Sara Hammon, played by Samantha Mathis.

Did *Billions* explain how Taylor hired her?

Comment: What's the point of your question? They hired her, just like companies hire people each day.

Comment: @BCdotWEB it looks like they are very close , which usually is not happening when companies just hire people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not precisely

The only "explanation" we get is from Taylor who says

> "It's a big part of why I asked Sara to become COO. Her reputation, first as Chief of Staff for the Supe*, - then in Silicon Valley."
>
> <sup>* I'm assuming this is the Superintendent of the Naval Academy at Annapolis as that institution is referened earlier.</sup>

The *implication* is that Sara was **headhunted** for the role of Chief Operating Officer but no doubt more information will be come available later in the season.